# PySpark - Does DataFrame.count() Cause a cache()?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

If I have a very large DataFrame on my PySpark cluster, does calling `df.count()` on it cause the entire DataFrame `df` to be brought into memory of a single node, or do all the individual nodes count their part of the structure and return it somewhere to be aggregated as a final result?

I don't see anything in the documentation to indicate this one way or the other.  Basically I don't want to call `count()` on a DataFrame that's too big to fit in the memory of any individual node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

count is something that can be distributed across executors. So, for each executor, count their number of records. Then send the aggregated number of records to be counted together. Spark optimizations will take care of those simple details.

If you call `collect()` then, that's what causes driver to be flooded with complete dataframe and most likely resulting in failure.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice on the spark is not to usee count and it's recommended to use `isEmpty` method instead of `count` method if it's possible. Also, all of the spark actions except `collect` method will run on the spark executors and the only result will return to the spark driver